# How to differentiate a Azure Temporary Storage Drive vs other drives on my Azure VM?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I created a Azure Virtual Machine and it in turn created a temporary storage drive for me (D:). Now, If I have C:, D:, E:,F: drive in my VM how can I differentiate which is Azure temporary Storage which is not.

I have tried to Use DeviceType=3 but it lists all the Logical Drives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, it looks there isn't any programmatic way to identify the Azure temporary drive. May be the hack is to look for "DATALOSS_WARNING_README.txt" file in all the drives.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're talking about Virtual Machines (you didn't specify). For VMs:

- Your OS disk is backed by durable blob storage. All the time. For Windows, this is approx. 127GB. For Linux, this is approx. 32GB.
- Your temp drive is always in-chassis, and at risk. The temp disk size is advertised in the VM sizing specs.

Beyond that: You'd be taking the specific action of mounting additional disks, which are all durable, blob-backed. So you'll know exactly which drives there are.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to identify the drive that is being used by Azure for temporary storage programmatically? I need this information to achieve something else and do not want to hard-code saying D: drive always.